# Xubuntu 22.04 no internet with ethernet

Tags: networking, xubuntu, ethernet

Recently just changed to r8168 driver due to slow network with cable. It worked fine just 2 days.Suddenly no internet. I tried to edit /etc/resolv.conf, but it showed same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.

Comment: I booted with other linus os. Network is fine.

Comment: <info>  [1705059518.5735] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
<info>  [1705059518.5735] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
<info>  [1705059518.6224] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
failed to open /run/network/ifstate
<info>  [1705059519.4321] manager: startup complete
<info>  [1705059524.9202] modem-manager: ModemManager not available
<info>  [1705059524.9945] modem-manager: ModemManager now available
<info>  [1705059553.5714] agent-manager: agent[1584ec66ce186ea8,:1.57/org.freedesktop.nm-applet/1000]: agent registered

Comment: service NetworkManger status
Unit NetworkManger.service could not be found.

service --status all
--status: unrecognized service

Comment: sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:e800(size=256) memory:febff000-febfffff memory:fbffc000-fbffffff memory:febc0000-febdffff